# RJAGS - How to pass more complex functions in BUGS file

Tags: r, jags, rjags

My goal is to basically migrate [this code](https://github.com/rtcovidlive/rtlive-global/blob/master/rtlive/model.py) to R.
All the preprocessing wrt datasets has been already done, now however I am stuck in writing the "model" file. As a first attempt, and for the sake of clarity, I wrote the code which is shown below in R language.

What I want to do is to run an MCMC to have an estimate of the parameter R_t, given the daily reported data for Italian Country.
The main steps that have been pursued are:

1. Sample an array parameter, namely the log(R_t), from a Gaussian RW distribution

```
Gauss_RandomWalk <- function(N, x0, mu, variance) {   
z <- cumsum(rnorm(n=N, mean=mu, sd=sqrt(variance)))   
t <- 1:N   
x <- (x0 + t*mu + z)   
return(x) 
}

log_R_t <- Gauss_RandomWalk(tot_dates, 0., 0., 0.035**2)
R_t_candidate <- exp(log_R_t)
```

2. Compute some quantities, that are function of this sampled parameters, namely the number of infections. This dependence is quite simple, since it is linear algebra:

```
infections <- rep(0. , tot_dates)
infections[1] <- exp(seed)
for (t in 2:tot_dates){
  infections[t] <- sum(R_t_candidate * infections * gt_to_convolution[t-1,])
}
```

3. Convolve the array I have just computed with a delay distribution (onset+reporting delay), finally rescaling it by the exposure variable:

```
test_adjusted_positive <- convolve(infections, delay_distribution_df$density, type = "open")
test_adjusted_positive <- test_adjusted_positive[1:tot_dates]
positive <- round(test_adjusted_positive*exposure)
```

4. Compute the Likelihood, which is proportional to the probability that a certain set of data was observed (i.e. daily confirmed cases), by sampling the aforementioned log(R_t) parameter from which the variable positive is computed.

```
likelihood <- dnbinom(round(Italian_data$daily_confirmed), mu = positive, size = 1/6)
```

Finally, here we come to my BUGS model file:

```
model {

  #priors as a Gaussian RW
  log_rt[1] ~ dnorm(0, 0.035)
  log_rt[2] ~ dnorm(0, 0.035)
  for (t in 3:tot_dates) {
    log_rt[t] ~ dnorm(log_rt[t-1] + log_rt[t-2], 0.035)
    R_t_candidate[t] <- exp(log_rt[t])
  }
  
    # data likelihood
    for (t in 2:tot_dates) {
        infections[t] <- sum(R_t_candidate * infections * gt_to_convolution[t-1,])
    }
    
    test_adjusted_positive <- convolve(infections, delay_distribution)
  test_adjusted_positive <- test_adjusted_positive[1:tot_dates]
  positive <- test_adjusted_positive*exposure

  for (t in 2:tot_dates) {
        confirmed[t] ~ dnbinom( obs[t], positive[t], 1/6) 
    }
}
```

where `gt_to_convolution` is a constant matrix, `tot_dates` is a constant value and `exposure` is a constant array.

When trying to compile it through:

```
data <- NULL
data$obs <- round(Italian_data$daily_confirmed)
data$tot_dates <- n_days
data$delay_distribution <- delay_distribution_df$density
data$exposure <- exposure
data$gt_to_convolution <- gt_to_convolution

inits <- NULL
inits$log_rt  <- rep(0, tot_dates)

library (rjags)
library (coda)

set.seed(1995)

model <- "MyModel.bug"
jm <- jags.model(model , data, inits)
```

It raises the following raising error:

```
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
Deleting model

Error in jags.model(model, data, inits) : RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 19.
Possible directed cycle involving test_adjusted_positive
```

Hence I am not even able to debug it a little, even though I'm pretty sure there is something wrong more in general but I cannot figure out what and why.

At this point, I think the best choice would be to implement a Metropolis Algorithm myself according to the likelihood above, but obviously, I would way much more prefer to use an already tested framework that is BUGS/JAGS, this is the reason why I am asking for help.

Comment: Is `convolve` an `rjags` function?

Comment: I assume so, since error is at line 19 (i.e. `positive <- test_adjusted_positive*exposure`)

Comment: Why do you assume so? I can't find it in the [`JAGS user manual`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/Manuals/4.x/) .

Comment: I think it would have risen error, I remember it used to tell when a function is not present. But you're right that it is not present.
What would you suggest to define more complex functions, such as for instance `convolve`?

Comment: I don't think it is particularly easy to include new complex functions in jags; in this regard things can be a bit easier in stan or maybe nimble (although I have not used it)

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. Or else I'm forced to implement a quite simple MC myself